# Построение круговой диаграммы средствами GDLib

Tags: php

Доброго времни суток Вам, жителям "ХэшКодчании". Я хочу средствами GDLib построить круговую диаграмму. Конечно же, я умею это делать, но как задать определённую величину центрального угла каждого сектора, увы , я не знаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Answer (score 2):

[Построение диаграмм средствами GDLib](http://blog.webmasterschool.ru/php/14/)